# Retrieve item which is sold more than twice

Tags: sql, ms-access

I have 3 tables;sale, sale_detail, item, and their relationship are sale 1:M sale_detail and item 1:M sale

in item table

```
item_id
1
2
3
4
```

in sale table

```
sale_id
1
2
3
```

in sale_detail table

```
sale_id    items_id
1          1
1          2
1          3
2          2
2          3
```

I want to retrieve item id which is sold more than twice.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use a group by with a having attribute

```
SELECT i.item_id
FROM sale_detail sd
    INNER JOIN item i ON sd.items_id = i.item_ID
    INNER JOIN sale s ON sd.sale_id = s.sale_id
GROUP BY i.item_id HAVING COUNT(s.sale_id) > 2
```